# In reference to the Chomsky hierarchy (and automatas), Which is the linear feedback shift register Languages/automaton?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

The Chomsky hierarchy is a guideline on language expressive power. The linear feedback shift register is a very interesting "element" to structure a language and there is a large theoretical literature.

In reference to the Chomsky hierarchy (and automata), which is the linear feedback shift register languages/automaton ?

Answer (score 1):

It has a *finite* memory, so it's just a DFA (or some of the output-producing variants). If you allow a growing/shrinking feedback register, it is probably equivalent to a Turing machine.

Comment: The  linear feedback shift register not allow rowing/shrinking , but it is an interesting information. Why do you think that growing / shrinking can make turing equivalent ? Do you have any scientific paper or link that you can send me?

Comment: @ClaudioMartines, as I say in my answer, the number of configurations is *finite*, and they are related by a *function*. There is a *starting configuration*, a definite *input alphabet*, and a set of *accepting configurations*. This is just a roundabout way of describing a DFA. What distinguishes a Turing machine is precisely that the amount of information it can keep in its tape is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you for your response. One question: 
if the register contains natural numbers and if there exist an algorithm (consisting only of logic xor gates) can cover all N,  could i say that it is Turing equivalent ?

Comment: @ClaudioMartines, in the moment you allow *unlimited* natural numbers into your automaton, it is a safe bet that it is equivalent to a Turing machine (just two unlimited integers, testing for zero, adding and substracting 1 under the control of a finite "program" is enough).